# Isito - Enable/disable envoy external auth http filter per route

Tags: kubernetes, istio, envoyproxy, istio-sidecar

I am trying to apply ext authz filter per route for my app but it is failing. Below are the filter configuration

step-1. Applied below configuration for the app and all the request are passing filter fine but i want the filter to disabled for specific route path , so i am using the step-2 as well

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: myFiltername
  namespace: myNamespace
spec:
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
    match:
      context: SIDECAR_INBOUND
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
            subFilter:
              name: envoy.filters.http.router
    patch:
      operation: INSERT_BEFORE
      value:
        name: envoy.ext_authz
        typed_config:
          '@type': type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.ext_authz.v3.ExtAuthz
          failure_mode_allow: false
          http_service:
            authorization_request:
              allowed_headers:
                patterns:
                - exact: Authorization
            path_prefix: /mypath
            server_uri:
              cluster: outbound|8080||myClusterName
              timeout: 6s
              uri: myClusterName:8080
          with_request_body:
            allow_partial_message: true
            max_request_bytes: 8192
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: myApp
```

step-2 To disable ext authz filter based on route or virtual service path. by passing routename i do not see any difference after applying step2 but when  matching the merger operation with header then calls made with header is by passing the filter but other calls are failing with 404 error

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: myFiltername-bypass
  namespace: myNamespace
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: myApp
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: HTTP_ROUTE
      match:
        context: SIDECAR_INBOUND
        routeConfiguration:
          portNumber: 8080
          vhost:
            name: inbound|http|8080
            # I tried with route name from virtual service but not working as expected
      patch:
        operation: MERGE
        value:
          match:
            headers:
              - name: some-header
                present_match: true
            prefix: /
          typed_per_filter_config:
            envoy.filters.http.ext_authz:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.ext_authz.v3.ExtAuthzPerRoute
              disabled: true
```